# JOptionPane output of double to 2 decimal places:

Tags: java

so I've finished yet another program for class and am trying to make it look a little more 'nice'. I've use JOptionPane for every question and selection but the output...Is there a way to use J-pane to output the answer to 2 decimal places as I have by System.ou.print?

Only posting a portion of the code of one method

```
public static void Celsius()  

 //First method used within Start to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit       
{

    double converted;
    double temperature;
    //user inputs temperature to be converted 
    temperature = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please enter the temperature in Celsius and press 'Ok'",
            "You selected Celsius to Fahrenheit",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));                                                      
    converted = 9/5.0*temperature+32;  
    //outputs converted temperature
    System.out.print("The converted temperature in Fahrenheit = ");
    System.out.printf(" %.2f", converted);         
    System.out.println(" degrees Fahrenheit");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (see also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html))

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String formatted = df.format(2.456345); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Result: " + formatted);   // shows 2.46
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I need to wait a bit then before trying this as it looks a bit beyond our class at the moment. I will try and wrap my head around it and hope to use that in the future.